# Using ScrollableResults and hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, scrollableresults

It's my first time trying this, but I'm getting the following error:

> The result set is closed

while trying to use `ScrollableResults`.

```
@Override
public void associarTodosConteudos(LoteTransferenciaTO lotetransferencia, UsuarioDepartamentoTO udLogado, Long idDepartamento, Long idUsuario) {
    // Lista os objetos controlados fluxo
    ScrollableResults objetos = this.persistencia.listarConteudosSR(idDepartamento, idUsuario);

    while (objetos.next()) {
        ContentTO content = (ContentTO) objetos.get(0);

        this.negocioVinculoLote.adicionarNoLoteTransferencia(lotetransferencia, content, udLogado);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, what's the type of this persistencia object?
I think the problem is there...

Answer (score 1):

`ScrollableResults` is closed once this method `this.persistencia.listarConteudosSR(idDepartamento, idUsuario);` is exited.

Try to iterate over the `ScrollableResults` inside `this.persistencia.listarConteudosSR(idDepartamento, idUsuario);` method. it should work.

for more details refer https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html